# MATLAB: alternative of Octave's function 'source' (import m-file)

Tags: matlab, octave

In Octave you can import a m-file source the function 'source' (see http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/source.html). I use it to create a lot of configuration parameters and source it from the main file.

MATLAB has no function 'source' and I cannot find an alternative. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just calling an m-file from a MATLAB script will import it into the script.

e.g. If I have a script configparameters.m where I define a=2, the script (in the same directory)

```
clear all;
configparameters;
disp(a)
```

will print the value 2 to the screen.

Answer (score 2):

[run](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/run.html) should pretty much be what you're looking for, if I understand the `source` documentation correctly.

EDIT:
It seems run refuses to run files other than m-files (and probably p-files etc.).
So probably need two functions in matlab (which you can obviously put together in your own `source` implementation):

```
eval(fileread(<filename>))
```

This reads the full text contained in `filename` and evaluates it.
Just as `source` apparently does.

Comment: I think `source` parses and execute the contents of the file, even if it isn't an *.m file. `run` is the closest thing but only works with MATLAB files.