# Importing multiple classes in single .m file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I've seen [MATLAB: alternative of Octave's function 'source' (import m-file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315668/matlab-alternative-of-octaves-function-source-import-m-file), but I cannot seem to figure out how the following works. This is for Matlab R2016b.

I'm looking at [M_files_chap12.zip](http://ant-s4.unibw-hamburg.de/dafx/DAFX_Book_Page_2nd_edition/M_files_chap12.zip), and in that .zip, there are two files:

- `WDFDiodeExample.m` which is runnable, and uses some additional classes
- `WDFClasses.m` which contain the additional classes

Here is a snippet of `WDFClasses.m`:

```matlab
% WDFclasses.m
% ....

%----------------------WDF Class------------------------
classdef WDF < hgsetget % the WDF element superclass
    properties 
        PortRes % the WDF port resistance
    end
    methods
            function Volts = Voltage(obj)  % the voltage (V) over a WDF element
                Volts = (obj.WU+obj.WD)/2; % as defined in the WDF literature
            end
    end;
end
%----------------------Adaptor Class------------------------
classdef Adaptor < WDF % the superclass for ser. and par. (3-port) adaptors
    properties
        KidLeft % a handle to the WDF element connected at the left port
        KidRight % a handle to the WDF element connected at the right port
    end;
end
...
```

The problem is, I cannot seem to import these classes from this file. I have tried adding each of the following statements at start of `WDFDiodeExample.m`:

```matlab
WDFClasses  %this will run WDFClasses.m; but % Class name and filename do not agree.
eval(fileread('WDFClasses.m')) % Error: Illegal use of reserved keyword "classdef".
run('WDFClasses.m') % Class name and filename do not agree.
```

... and I get the errors written in the comments.

It seems that MATLAB wants **only** one-class-per-m-file, and it doesn't seem to recognize multiple classes packed in a single file - but then, why would the authors choose to write the `WDFClasses.m` like that so it is unusable directly? Or was this possible in earlier versions of MATLAB, and then got disabled?

Comment: Yes, MATLAB requires only one class per file.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, the associated literature also mentions this:

> It must be noted that all the presented classes are shown in a
>   single M-file for compactness although in practice MATLAB requires each class to reside in an
>   individual file. In other words, the classes ... should be split into seven different files
>   in order for the model to run in MATLAB.

... so I guess, that is just the way it works...